# Java JTable - First click on column to sort by descending

Tags: java, sorting, jtable

I have a Java JTable which stores about 8000 rows, with 10 columns, and all works well.

When I click on a column header, the whole JTable will be sorted by the data in that column in ascending order in the first instance, clicking again will then sort the data in descending order.

I would like to change this behaviour on one specific column (double column - stores %'s) so that the first click will sort the data in descending order, and the second click will then be ascending - as I am most interested in the entries with the highest %s.

This is not about changing the original sort order when the table is first presented. The table is originally sorted by ID number (first column) ascending which is what I want.

This is about changing the behaviour when re-sorting based on other columns, so that the first click will be descending order.

Any one got any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

```
    int noOfClicks = 1;
    public void arrange(){

TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<>(table.getModel());
table.setRowSorter(sorter);
List<RowSorter.SortKey> sortKeys = new ArrayList<>();

int columnIndexToSort = 1;
    if (noOfClicks%2==0){ 
    //firstClick
    sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(columnIndexToSort,   SortOrder.ASCENDING));

    }else{
   sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(columnIndexToSort, SortOrder.DESCENDING));
    }
    ++noOfClicks;


sorter.setSortKeys(sortKeys);
sorter.sort();    

    }
```

you can do it with above approach.if you can store the noOfclicks
then you can check whether you should arrange it by assending order or descending order. if the noOfclicks is a even number then you can arrange the table on assending order.no of clicks will be incremented by +1 on each click.

Comment: Thanks for help. So the noOfClicks would need to be stored per column? As it is only for one column that I want to change the default order. I was thinking that may be someway to change the underlying data table/model an modify and column's asc/desc ordering

Comment: there is no need to store `noofclicks` per column. made some changes to the code just change the `columnIndexToSort` to whatever the column index you need to arrange then this will do the job. note that index start with 0

Comment: OK thanks, so I will need to call the arrange() method everytime a JTable header is clicked on? which will then determine the noOfClicks for asc/desc. But won't this be influenced by the total number of clicks recorded across all tables in the column. noOfClicks will increase every time a column header is clicked on won't it? So if I add in a line that only increments noOfClicks if the desired column is the selected one that should work. But then, if I resort based on another column, that won't be possible anymore will it? I want to maintain the default sort functionality on all other columns

Comment: `int index = convertColumnIndexToModel(columnAtPoint(mouseEvent.getPoint()));` i assume that you have added a actionListner to the jtableheader . you can get the index of the clicked column with above code and then with an help of a if loop inside the method you can add your desired functions.

Answer (score 1):

I extended the TableRowSorter class to get the desired effect. In my case I wanted to sort all columns descending first, except for the first column. The following code allows to specify which columns should be sorted ascending first.

```
/** Class sorting table descending on first click unless column is specified
 * in constructor to follow standard behaviour (ascending on first click).
 * @author Adam Jagosz */
class NormallyDescendingSorter extends TableRowSorter {

    /** columns to be sorted in a standard way, ascending on first click */
    ArrayList<Integer> ascendingColumns;

    /** Constructor
     * @param model table model to be sorted
     * @param ascendingColumns columns to follow ascending sort on first click */
    public NormallyDescendingSorter(TableModel model, int... ascendingColumns) {
        super(model);
        this.ascendingColumns = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int index = 0; index < ascendingColumns.length; index++)
        {
            this.ascendingColumns.add(ascendingColumns[index]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method sorting table rows upon clicking on column header
     * @param column column to sort by */
    @Override
    public void toggleSortOrder(int column) {
        if(ascendingColumns.contains(column)) {
            super.toggleSortOrder(column);
            return;
        }
        ArrayList<SortKey> sortKeys = new ArrayList<>(getSortKeys());
        if(sortKeys.isEmpty() || sortKeys.get(0).getColumn() != column) {
            sortKeys.add(0, new RowSorter.SortKey(column, SortOrder.DESCENDING));
        }
        else if (sortKeys.get(0).getSortOrder() == SortOrder.ASCENDING) {  
            sortKeys.removeIf(key -> key.getColumn() == column);
            sortKeys.add(0, new RowSorter.SortKey(column, SortOrder.DESCENDING));
        }
        else {
            sortKeys.removeIf(key -> key.getColumn() == column);
            sortKeys.add(0, new RowSorter.SortKey(column, SortOrder.ASCENDING));
        }
        setSortKeys(sortKeys);
    }
}
```

You can use this like that:

```
DocumentTableModel model = new DocumentTableModel(document);
JTable table = new JTable(model);
NormallyDescendingSorter sorter = new NormallyDescendingSorter(model, 0);
table.setRowSorter(sorter);
```

(I specified 0 as column index to be sorted ascending).

Comment: This answer should be accepted.  I implemented something similar to this, using the toggleSortOrder from DefaultRowSorter based on this idea and it worked perfectly!